# intercept a control being rendered in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, interceptor

I am currently implementing the security layer for a spring MVC app using Spring Security.
However I am interested in modifying the behavior of certain controls depending on the role of the user whos logged in. By behavior i mean read / hide / R.W.
But what I want, is to let an interceptor do the job for me. Ideally, by intercepting a certain control X (could be a custom control i created) and modifying its state (state being a custom property).

In brief, I know that Spring Security handles resource and methods, but what I would like to do is to intercept and modify the behavior of a custom control before it renders. is that possible?

Many thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use your `UserDetailsService` outside of the security context since its just a DAO. You can just inject it in your spring context like any other bean.

The `UserDetailsService#loadUserByUsername(String username)` method should return the roles for your users, given that it is set up properly, you can use them to determine how to render your controls.

[Here](http://www.codercorp.com/blog/spring/security-spring/writing-custom-userdetailsservice-for-spring-security.html) is a good howto on implementing a `UserDetailsService` properly.

You can use it your security context, so your filters know about the roles:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref="myDetailsService" />
</authentication-manager>
```

You can also use it as a normal bean:

```
<bean id="myDetailsService"
    class="com.company.service.impl.MyDetailsService" />
<bean id="myOtherService"
    class="com.company.service.impl.OtherService" >
    <property name="detailsService" ref="myDetailsService"/>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the User object in the session and have your interceptor check its roles. I don't know about an easy out-of-the-box annotation for this, although with Spring you never know - it might exist.

Comment: thanks for the input, however what I would like to know is if it is possible from the interceptor to catch the instance of a control being rendered.

Comment: Ah so. Do you really want to create a tightly-coupled interceptor that knows your controller and accesses its properties? How about decorating your request attributes to indicate the required behavior? Slightly more generic approach, similar to a filter chain. If you do want to, I guess you could just inject the controller into the interceptor as a dependency and access it. This would require the controller beans to be singletons, but I think they are by default.

Comment: Yep that could be an option. I thought that by letting the Interceptor or ideally the spring login module control the views on my web app, I can separate the security layer from the app completely, so the the devs wont have to worry about "who can see this and that", and just concentrate on other tasks. The problem with spring security annotations is that I need define the roles at design time, which isnt possible since roles are retrieved from a db at runtime (in my case).

Comment: Roles being retrieved from the DB at runtime is not a novelty. Hard-wiring these roles into the code is not a problem as long as the roles are not created dynamically within the application. If they are, you probably need to model the 'Permission' concept and reflect (all possible combinations of) permissions in your code's behavior. It sounds like your use case is not very unique and if this is so I advise not to reinvent too many wheels here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion :). Its defintly not unique, I already implemented this model in .Net. I already have alternatives, but just curious about the potential of interceptors in java.